How to Modify YOLO Model in NCNN Android App to Return Label and Class Probability?
I’m working on an object detection app based on the YOLOv8 model in the NCNN Android implementation. The source code for the app I’m modifying is from this repository: ncnn-android-yolov8.
I need to display the detection results, including the class label and the probability (confidence score) for each detected object. The goal is to store the captured image with the bounding box detection, label, and probability in Firebase.
Currently, I cannot extract the label and probability (prob) values from the detection results. I’ve added the following custom function to the yolo.cpp file located at ncnn-android-yolov8/app/src/main/jni to try and extract these values:
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, float>> Yolo::get_classnames_and_scores(const std::vector<Object>& objects) {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, float>> results;
    for (const auto& obj : objects) {
        std::string label = class_names[obj.label]; // assuming class_names holds the labels
        float prob = obj.prob;
        results.emplace_back(label, prob);
    }
    return results;
}


Here are my specific questions:

Can I modify the existing detection function in the yolo.cpp file to return both the label and the probability for each detection?
If modifying the function isn’t possible, how can I integrate this custom function to return the class label and probability values for each detected object?
What is the best way to integrate this functionality into the app to store the results (image, bounding boxes, labels, and probabilities) in Firebase?

Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!
Note: I don’t have any background in developing Android apps, so I searched for an app to try deploying my model. A friend helped me modify the app, and this is the problem we’ve encountered.
